# How do I kill the sandworm?

Tags: sega-genesis, dune-2

In 'Dune : The Battle for Arrakis' for Sega Genesis, a sandworm seems to randomly come and eat units that stay too long on the sand. They also seem to have a health bar and can be targeted and shot at. However, I have never been able to shoot them till their health bar drops down to zero. They are too fast and always get away before that happens. However, next time I see a sandworm it always seems to  have a full health bar.  I am not even sure if it's always the same sandworm with a rejuvenated health bar or a different sandworm every time.

Is it possible to destroy the sandworm? I could only find speculations on Google, so I was wondering if someone has been able to do it.

Comment: @editor: I don't think that game was called Dune 2

Comment: The OP is correct to say that the game was not called Dune 2 on the Sega Genesis, as it was simply named "Dune: The Battle for Arrakis". However, on non-Sega platforms, such as the Amiga or PC, the game was known as "Dune II: Battle for Arrakis" in Europe and "Dune II: Building of a Dynasty" elsewhere. On these non-Sega platforms, the original game Dune was an adventure game (not an RTS) so the sequel was given the name Dune II and so the tag [tag:dune2] is appropriate.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I don't believe anyone ever did find a way to kill the sandworm (on the Amiga or the PC), but I can find no evidence to support an answer one way or the other.

Comment: I finally dug up my old PC copy and it defintely reads "Dune II: Battle for Arrakis," despite my living in the US. So either some parts of the US got the European distribution, or wikipedia got something wrong.

Comment: tag synonym requested to prevent this confusion in the future :https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12633/dune2-tag-synomyms

Comment: fwiw its not the same worm, there can be multiple worms on a map, at least it was that way for the PC version.  Some weapons are extra effective against it, like the sonic tank for house atredies.  otherwise, just line up seige tanks or your best tanks on rocks and try to bait them by placing some expendable unit on the sand.

Comment: Shoot it until it dies.

Answer (score 4):

The worm doesn't die, you can only bring it to 1/2 of its health and then it disappears. It's best to just leave them alone

source: https://www.gamefaqs.com/genesis/586152-dune-the-battle-for-arrakis/faqs/1519

Comment: It's been ages and my reference is the PC version, but I'm pretty sure it /was/ possible to kill it eventually as it doesn't regenerate between reappearances, and when it dies the final death it releases a spice field.

Comment: @Shadur Sega version was different in this case. I can't remember if the FAQ is right about the disappearing when at half HP thing, but worms were definitely returning at full HP.

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to position your units along the edge of rock - if the sandworm comes along they'll attack automatically. It does have a lot of health but will eventually be chased off while you concentrate on base building and raising your army.